# How to prevent ScrollView to hide footer?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

There is a header and footer on the screen while the center of the screen (Content Area) is occupied by `ScrollView`. When I start the app, the footer is shown. But, when I click on element "A", it reveals more elements on the screen, pushing other elements below. The `ScrollView` does make the central part scrollable, but it also hides the footer (a gray `LinearLayout` on the bottom of the screen).

How can I make footer remains on the bottom of the screen? I want Content Area to scroll only. Header and Footer XMLs are outside of the `ScrollView` element. I tried using `RelativeLayout` for the footer instead of `LinearLayout`, but without any success.

Here is the look before and after the click on the element "A".

[image: Before click]

[image: After click]

I may provide the code, XML and Java, if needed, but it's pretty much of the code.

Comment: Please put your whole xml so we can understand how to maintain whole layout. and we can help you more proper way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

use weight for layout

Comment: `android:layout_weight="1"` works for making view on top with `match_parent/fill_parent` respect the view below's `wrap_content` height.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Header view" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    //////////////



    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Footer View" />
```

Comment: This way the lowest part of the scrollview is hidden behind the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollviews direct child must not have attribuute of height to wrapcontent. i think you declared wrapcontent isnt it? that views height must have height of not resizable